# how to detect mobile browser in yaws (erlang)

Tags: http, mobile, erlang, http-headers, yaws

I know I can get the user agent from the Arg struct but how can I tell it is from a mobile browser (i.e. android or iPhone Safari), and then redirect to the appropriate mobile page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might first want to [read up on the pros and cons of detection via the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). Once you decide how to proceed and you still want to use redirects, you can use [the redirection support in Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/redirect.yaws) to redirect to different pages.

Comment: It was a simple website that needs a mobile version.  The redirect did help and I am using re:run to case it. Thanks